# TYPO3 url language error

Tags: typo3, realurl

I install realurl extension in my website for TYPO3 7.6.15 but the URL for language don't function! For example: 
this is in english: http://www.hotel-centrale.it/newsite/en/camere-auronzo-di-cadore/camera-economy/

must be: http://www.hotel-centrale.it/newsite/en/rooms-auronzo-di-cadore/economy-room/

Comment: Please post your realurl version and the pagePath section (at least) of your realurl configuration. What‘s that `newsite` segment? - I thought it were a new instance in a subfolder our similar, but it obviously isn‘t. Maybe your problem originate here, as localized page paths seem to work for the rest of your site!?

Comment: This is most often caused by an incorrect languages setup. Did you create english and italian languages in the root of your page tree? Did you setup the realurl path translation functionality?